# 17 renderings before showing view - React JS

Tags: reactjs, performance, view, rendering, console.log

I'm starting in React. I'm working on an old project that does 17 renderings before showing a view. I have no idea where the problem is. Has anyone ever experienced a problem like this that can help me? I realized this when I needed to make a console.log and i had the console back 17 times.

Comment: No way to know without seeing the code. Maybe it is setting state 16 times.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.